# How to download base docker image for creating hello world docker image?

Tags: image, download, docker

I'm very starting position in docker. I'm trying to create helloworld docker image which requires some base image. I'm working in intranet network. So, how can I get base image??. I'm using Redhat linux 7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Docker automatically downloads the base image you specify in your Dockerfile. So, for example, a really simple "hello-world" image could be;

contents of your Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine
CMD echo "hello-world"
```

Building an image from the Dockerfile, and naming it "hello":

```
docker build -t hello .
```

You'll see Docker pulling the `alpine` image, if it isn't there yet, and then building the image;

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon 2.048 kB
Step 1 : FROM alpine
 ---> 70c557e50ed6
Step 2 : CMD echo "hello world"
 ---> Running in 94fcb9b89aaa
 ---> 6462a272b1d6
Removing intermediate container 94fcb9b89aaa
Successfully built 6462a272b1d6
```

You can then run a container from the image (this image will just run, and exit directly after its done)

```
$ docker run hello
hello world
```

You can use *any* image as a "base" (`FROM`) image for your own images, so any image you find on Docker Hub can be used as a base.

However, in general, it's recommended to use the "official" images as a base for your own images. There are various "distros" available, such as Ubuntu, Debian, Alpine (if you want a lightweight image), CentOS, etc. The base image doesn't have to match the distro of your host (so you can use "ubuntu" for your images even though you have Red Hat running on your host)

You can find the official images here; https://hub.docker.com/explore/

For a more advanced "hello world" image, see the documentation here; https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockerizing/

And best practices for writing Dockerfiles; https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/

Comment: Thanks thaJeztah. But I'm working in intranetwork where I'm not able to download any base image. So, is their a way to download image file and paste it to my local repo of docker.??

Comment: If you're developing in an environment where no internet connection is allowed, you can `docker pull` the base image on a system that *has* internet connection, and export the base image using https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/, and load them using `docker load`. That gives full control over which image(s) are available, and are allowed to be used. Alternatively, set up a private repository that developers can connect to, to pull images.

Comment: Note that a local repository can act as a mirror for docker hub; I think it's possible to have that working as well, if there's no internet connection. This would give you the option of using official images, but don't give developers an option to pull additional images.

Comment: Thanks thaJeztah.docker save and load commands helped me to copy images.

Answer (score 0):

**Create a full image using tar**

In general, you’ll want to start with a working machine that is running the distribution you’d like to package as a base image, though that is not required for some tools like Debian’s `Debootstrap`, which you can also use to build Ubuntu images.

It can be as simple as this to create an Ubuntu base image:

```
$ sudo debootstrap raring raring > /dev/null
$ sudo tar -C raring -c . | docker import - raring
a29c15f1bf7a
$ docker run raring cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=13.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=raring
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 13.04"
```

There are more example scripts for creating base images in the Docker GitHub Repo:

- [Red hat Enterprise Linux](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/contrib/mkimage-yum.sh)
- [BusyBox](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/contrib/mkimage-busybox.sh)
- [Debian / Ubuntu](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/contrib/mkimage-debootstrap.sh)

Comment: In general I would not recommend to try and build your own base images; the official base images are well maintained and are scanned for vulnerabilities. It's easy to mess up Building your own base images, and requires time and effort to keep them up to date